# Order of execution in loop

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, for-loop, async.js

I'm using this function to get some infos from google analytics and  trying to stick them in a JS object in order to send it to the user.

My problem is: the `console.log(obj)` gets executed before the `obj.push(tempObj);`. So when I try to send the `obj`, I find it empty.

I tried to use `async.each()` & `async.waterfall()` but still had the same problem.

```js
function getJsonFileByUser2() {
  authClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
    let dimensions, webproperties;
    let accounts = getAccountsByUser();
    let obj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
      let tempObj = {
        account_id: accounts[i]["id"],
        account_name: accounts[i]["name"],
        webproperties: []
      };
      webproperties = getWebPropertyIdByAccount(accounts[i]["id"]);
      for (let j = 0; j < webproperties.length; j++) {
        dimensions = getDimensions(accounts[i]["id"], webproperties[j]["id"]);
        tempObj.webproperties.push({
          id: webproperties[j]["id"],
          name: webproperties[j]["name"],
          dimensions: dimensions
        });
      }
      obj.push(tempObj);
    }
    console.log(obj);
  });
}
```

Comment: @DanielWilliams: It does process according to the written order. It definitely does. Its just that the developer need to be aware of the things likes non-blocking IOs and `Promise`s.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: It completely waits for the `for` loop to be processed first. Please, refer to the docs.

Comment: @ZeekHuge as far as i know it do not wait

Comment: How can **ANY** programming language do that ? Seriously ? JS **DOES** wait for the for loop to complete ! One just needs to know how to handle async tasks

Comment: Did you try to confirm that `accounts` itself is not empty ? try `console.log(accounts)` before the `for` loop.

Comment: i've tried thatn the accounts variable isn't empty. i think the problem is the console.log(obj) get executed before the end of the for loop

Comment: Make the function `async` and use an await on the `obj.push(tempObj)`

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual code? Neither of `getAccountsByUser`, `getWebPropertyIdByAccount` and `getDimensions` is asynchronous? And you didn't place the `console.log` outside of the `authClient.authorize` callback by accident? Then no, `console.log(accounts)` does *not* get executed before the end of the loop. What makes you think it does?